# Installing aarch64-elf for barebones compilation on raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, bare-metal

I'm following this tutorial but it doesn't explain how to install aarch64-elf. Can someone explain how to do this on the Raspberry Pi 3B(running raspberry pi OS).

The command that will be run with it is: 
`aarch64-elf-as -c boot.S -o boot.o`

I'm not opposed to installing a new OS

Comment: The 3B will run RaspiOS 64. Try booting that and building things natively.

Comment: I need the barebones compiler